# How do you add a prefix to custom bash commands?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have written some custom bash commands in a shell file (abc.sh) and added them to my bash_profile.

```
function version() {
    log "Versioning..."

    git tag -a v$1 -m "$1" && npm publish && git push && git push --tags
}
```

~/.bash_profile

```
export PATH="/bin/abc.sh/:PATH"
```

To run the command I enter just:

```
version 1.0.0
```

However, I want to add the prefix 'abc':

```
abc version 1.0.0
```

Just like npm, bower, or git all require prefixes to run their commands.

Comment: Then your command is `abc` and one of the parameters is `version`

Comment: To avoid disabling your shell, replace `export PATH="/bin/abc.sh/:PATH"` with `export PATH="/bin/abc.sh/:$PATH"`

Comment: Better yet, use `PATH=/bin:$PATH`.  You put directories in PATH, not files.

Answer (score 0):

With your setup you could add directory with "abc.sh" to your `PATH` (instead of adding the script itself) and make it executable (optionally renaming it to just "abc"). The in the script use first argument (a sub-command, e.g. "version") to select (using `case`) appropriate function and pass all remaining arguments to it.